# Using ACF true/false field on WooCommerce single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce site and in the single product page I have a custom checkbox to agree to terms before the add to cart button, but I am trying to add a true/false field in the dashboard so that this checkbox can be moved to a different position on the page.

My functions look like this:

```php
add_action( 'acf/init', "acf_move_checkbox", 10 );

function acf_move_checkbox() {
  
  $move_cart = get_field('move_cart');

    if ($move_cart) {

        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', "acf_product_terms", 10 );

    } else {

        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', "acf_product_terms", 10 );

    }

// More code

}
```

And nothing is happening, am I along the right lines with this or way off?

Comment: Not sure if `acf/init` would be the correct point in the hook processing sequence for this. Any different result if you try to hook this into just the general `init`, or `wp_loaded`?

Comment: At `acf/init` there is no queried object available. Everything in `functions.php` is outside [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). `get_field()` can't find anything to get data from so you'll to sort that first.

Comment: A Quick & Dirty solution is to use an [Options Page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/) in ACF.
Your `get_field()` will need a second argument: `get_field('move_cart', 'option')`. But that would globalise the option and that might not be what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately adding this to options wouldn't work as specific products would need targeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `acf/init` is similar to the WordPress init action, I wouldn't use it.

Init hooks are performed constantly.. since you want to apply an action on the single product page it's best to use a hook that only applies to that page, and will only run on those kinds of pages.

For example you can use the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook. It might also be useful to test fields by hard coding before retrieving them.

---

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_single_product_summary() {
    // Get field
    //$move_cart = get_field( 'move_cart' );
    
    // Set true OR false
    $move_cart = false;

    // When true
    if ( $move_cart ) {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'my_callback_function', 9 );
    } else {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'my_callback_function', 9 );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'action_woocommerce_single_product_summary', 1 );

function my_callback_function() {
    echo '<p style="color: red; font-size: 20px;">Hello World!</p>';
}
```

If the above step works, you can replace the hard coded field with the desired code/field

Comment: That works, thank you ever so much, gives me a good foundation as I have other similar functions that need implementing.